# How to connect UDL file to a Msaccess DB 2007 (Protected with password)?

Tags: ms-access-2007

The UDL file was connected `to MS Access DB 2007` successfully. However, when I have protected the DB with a user the connection failed.
Can any one show us how to solve this problem ?

[image: DB driver Name]

[image: Connection successful before password]

[image: This error after password enabled]

Comment: connection string seems to be incorrect. have you check?

Comment: Yes, I did but it failed

Comment: Check this: https://forums.asp.net/t/1763954.aspx?How+to+fix+Test+connection+failed+because+of+an+error+in+initializing+provider+

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways to solve this problem.
First, I have opened the 'UDL' file using a text editor and change it as follows :

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source='Your_DB_Full_Name';
Persist Security Info=False;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password='Your_Database_Password'
```

Second, I have viewed the `UDL` file properties (mouse right click) then:

1. At the Provider, tab select the driver.
2. At the All tab, double click on the `Data Source` property and write the full name of your DB (with full path).
3. At the all tab, double click on `Jet OLEDB:Database Password` property and write your DB password.
4. At the All tab, double click on the `User ID` property and write your DB user if it was different from Admin.
5. Finally, click OK.

[image]